# AngularJS ng-show and ng-hide doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

having a problem with angularjs logic here

I want to show the login link only when there is no user loggedin, and only show the logout link to logged in user, but it doesnt work properly

my HTML

```
 <section ng-controller="a" ng-show="auth = false">
    <a href="#/signin" ng-click="signin()"> Sign in </a>
 </section>

 <section ng-controller="b" ng-show="auth = true">
    <a href="#/signout" ng-click="signout()"> Sign out </a>
 </section>
```

The sign in is working well

this is my Controller

login Controller

```
 function ($scope, Service){
 $scope.auth = true;
 $scope.signin = function($event, userID, passwd){ 

                 Service.signin(userID,passwd).then( 
                        function (response){
                            $scope.auth = true; 
                  });
 }]).
```

logout Controller

```
  function ($scope, Service){
  $scope.auth = false; 
  $scope.signout = function($event){ 
                 Service.signout().then( 
                        function (response){
                            $scope.auth = false;    
                  });
  }]).
```

those 2 log out and log in links are basically in my main page. I dont want to create a lot of pages, therefore I want to hide each other. When the user click the log in link, it will run the angularjs router, in this case /login, there is another templateURL for the form and it will be appended directly to the main page. Once the user has typed in the userID and password, the user need to click submit button, this is the code

```
<form role="form" name="form1">
    <label for"userID">UserID</label><input type="text" id="userID" ng-model="userID">
    <label for"passwd">Password</label><input type="text" id="passwd" ng-model="passwd">
    <button data-ng-click="signin($event,userID,passwd); reload()">Login</button>
```

the reload() function will directly refresh the page. I am using the $window.location.reload()

Comment: Try this `ng-show="auth"` and `ng-show="!auth"`

Comment: doesn't work sir. I have tried this

Comment: I think it can just be ```ng-show="auth"``` for both of them. Then if the statement is true it will show, and if false it will be hidden

Comment: when I use that, the logout is not displayed at all sir

Comment: You need triple equals in the ng-show `ng-show='auth === false'` NOT `ng-show='auth = false'`. To make it even simpler, use `ng-show='auth'` for the login and `ng-show='!auth'` for the logout.

Comment: You have two different $scope make it $root '

Comment: are you using `$http` call inside service ? or it is jquery ajax?

Comment: i use http.get inside my service sir

Comment: does you `$scope.auth = true;` code is getting executed?

Comment: yes sir. i think there is the problem, if i put the $scope.auth=true, the condition will be always true right

Answer (score 1):

Your equals comparison is incorrect.

This is assigning a value of false to auth:

```
ng-show="auth = false"
```

What you want is this (double and triple equals do comparisons)

```
ng-show="auth === false"
```

You can also do this:

```
<section ng-controller="a" ng-show="!auth">
    <a href="#/signin" ng-click="signin()"> Sign in </a>
 </section>

 <section ng-controller="b" ng-show="auth">
    <a href="#/signout" ng-click="signout()"> Sign out </a>
 </section>
```

Comment: Sure, I'm just trying to make a point that a single equals is an assignment operator.

Comment: Sir, it is not working. I put the condition in my controller as auth = false and auth=true, is that correct?

Comment: No, look at my answer.  A single equals sign is an assignment operator.  Double and triple equals do comparison.  Use the second half of my example where I use !auth and auth in the ng-show

Comment: when i use the !auth and auth, the log in and log out link is totally not displayed when there is no user logged in

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually You need Two works for this task

### First Work:-

You need to assign `auth` varibale in `$rootScope` not `$scope`. *because this object used in two controller.*

Like

```
function ($scope, dataService, $rootScope){
 $scope.auth = true;
 $scope.signin = function($event, userID, passwd){ 

                 Service.signin(userID,passwd).then( 
                        function (response){
                            $rootScope.auth = true; 
                  });
 }]).
```

## Second Work:

You need to change `ng-show="auth = false"` to `ng-show="auth === false"`. You have used single equal. *it should be **double** or **triple** equal*

OR

if you assigned the object in $rootScope, then you don't need to check the condition for is true or false in the element. because you already define   `auth` is false or true in your controller. So you can just call `ng-show="auth` only.

Comment: still not working sir i have tried all the sugesstion. basically the function is working after the user click the link, is there any problem with that? When i use the double or tripe equal, both of the links are not displayed

Comment: I think your problem is your link button is out of angularjs, like that is your main screen? correct? also your main screan have not any controller?

Comment: i have edited the information sir. please take a look

Comment: sir i am using http call inside my service. is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just try the following

```
ng-show="auth"
```

Please let me know if it is still not working..

Comment: not working sir, when there is user logged in, the log out link is not displayed, but the log in link is

Comment: Say `var a = true;` You can do either `if(a === true)` to check if it's true, or `if(a)`. `if(a)` is shorthand for a being true. If you want to check if a is false, you would use `if(a === false)` or shorthand `if(!a)`. So `if(a)` will execute the code inside the if, `if(!a)` will not, as `a` isn't false.